# imap_body() returning empty string

Tags: php, email, imap

Hello fellow developers,

Im currently trying to read all emails with imap. Im trying to get the header infos with imap_headerinfo and the body with imap_fetchbody. 
However, I get all the headerinfo but I only get an empty string as a return from the fetchbody function. I hope someone can help me

```
$this->inbox = imap_open($server, $user, $password);

    // Header und Body der Email auslesen
    $emails = imap_search($this->inbox,'ALL');
    foreach($emails as $k) {
        $this->email_contents[$k] = array(
            'header' => imap_headerinfo($this->inbox, $k),
            'body' => imap_fetchbody($this->inbox, $k, '1')
        );
    }
    imap_close($this->inbox);
```

fetch_structure

```
    object(stdClass)#65 (11) {
  ["type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["encoding"]=>
  int(0)
  ["ifsubtype"]=>
  int(1)
  ["subtype"]=>
  string(5) "MIXED"
  ["ifdescription"]=>
  int(0)
  ["ifid"]=>
  int(0)
  ["ifdisposition"]=>
  int(0)
  ["ifdparameters"]=>
  int(0)
  ["ifparameters"]=>
  int(1)
  ["parameters"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#66 (2) {
      ["attribute"]=>
      string(8) "boundary"
      ["value"]=>
      string(36) "------------CC4C1146391EA6C129642420"
    }
  }
  ["parts"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#67 (12) {
      ["type"]=>
      int(0)
      ["encoding"]=>
      int(1)
      ["ifsubtype"]=>
      int(1)
      ["subtype"]=>
      string(5) "PLAIN"
      ["ifdescription"]=>
      int(0)
      ["ifid"]=>
      int(0)
      ["lines"]=>
      int(30)
      ["bytes"]=>
      int(590)
      ["ifdisposition"]=>
      int(0)
      ["ifdparameters"]=>
      int(0)
      ["ifparameters"]=>
      int(1)
      ["parameters"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#68 (2) {
          ["attribute"]=>
          string(7) "charset"
          ["value"]=>
          string(5) "utf-8"
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#69 (2) {
          ["attribute"]=>
          string(6) "format"
          ["value"]=>
          string(6) "flowed"
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#70 (13) {
      ["type"]=>
      int(5)
      ["encoding"]=>
      int(3)
      ["ifsubtype"]=>
      int(1)
      ["subtype"]=>
      string(4) "JPEG"
      ["ifdescription"]=>
      int(0)
      ["ifid"]=>
      int(0)
      ["bytes"]=>
      int(1036)
      ["ifdisposition"]=>
      int(1)
      ["disposition"]=>
      string(10) "attachment"
      ["ifdparameters"]=>
      int(1)
      ["dparameters"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#71 (2) {
          ["attribute"]=>
          string(8) "filename"
          ["value"]=>
          string(11) "logo_sm.jpg"
        }
      }
      ["ifparameters"]=>
      int(1)
      ["parameters"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#72 (2) {
          ["attribute"]=>
          string(4) "name"
          ["value"]=>
          string(11) "logo_sm.jpg"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that this Email does not have a section '1'.  Have a look at what  imap_fetchstructure($this->inbox, $k) shows.

Comment: As seen in the answer by @mr-heelis , I suspect the Email has an attachment so '1' will probably need to be '1.1'.  I only say this because it is already hardcoded (before someone downvotes me)

Comment: I tried it but im still not able to get any body even if I only go for imap_body() and not the fetch function. the string is allways empty. If i go for imap_fetchbody(....., ...., '0') then i get some body informations but still not the text.

Comment: Did you try imap_fetchstructure as per my first comment. It will be useful to know what that contains.

Comment: I did add it to my initial question now sorry

Comment: The Email consists of a PLAIN message with a JPG attachment. If the sender did not type a message then 1.1 would be blank.  Try making fetching body '1.2'  which will attempt to load the JPG.   I think your code is working but that message just happens to have no body.

Comment: 1.2 is also empty :/

Comment: Clutching at straws - I assume your $server is something like {mail.server.com:143}  and not {mail.server.com:110}  i.e. You are talking to an IMAP server, not POP3.  You can connect to an pop3 server with php imap, but not all commands work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

imap-fetchbody() works unusually when handling attached email messages and it's behaviour is inconsistent.

I was going to re-write this but to be honest the author atamido does a fantastic job of showing why this happens so i'll humbly cite his lead comment from this:: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php he also includes an example of how to extract the body

> imap-fetchbody() will decode attached email messages inline with the
>   rest of the email parts, however the way it works when handling
>   attached email messages is inconsistent with the main email message.
>           With an email message that only has a text body and does not have any mime attachments, imap-fetchbody() will return the following
>   for each requested part number:
>
> ```
> (empty) - Entire message
> 0 - Message header
> 1 - Body text
>     With an email message that is a multi-part message in MIME format, and contains the message text in plain text and HTML, and has
> ```
>
> a file.ext attachment, imap-fetchbody() will return something like the
>   following for each requested part number:
>
> ```
> (empty) - Entire message
> 0 - Message header
> 1 - MULTIPART/ALTERNATIVE
> 1.1 - TEXT/PLAIN
> 1.2 - TEXT/HTML
> 2 - file.ext
> ```
>
> Now if you attach the above email to an email with the message text in plain text and HTML, imap_fetchbody() will use this type of
>   part number system:
>
> ```
> (empty) - Entire message
> 0 - Message header
> 1 - MULTIPART/ALTERNATIVE
> 1.1 - TEXT/PLAIN
> 1.2 - TEXT/HTML
> 2 - MESSAGE/RFC822 (entire attached message)
> 2.0 - Attached message header
> 2.1 - TEXT/PLAIN
> 2.2 - TEXT/HTML
> 2.3 - file.ext
> ```
>
> Note that the file.ext is on the same level now as the plain text and
>   HTML, and that there is no way to access the MULTIPART/ALTERNATIVE in
>   the attached message.
>
> Here is a modified version of some of the code from previous posts
>   that will build an easily accessible array that includes accessible
>   attached message parts and the message body if there aren't multipart
>   mimes.  The $structure variable is the output of the
>   imap_fetchstructure() function.  The returned $part_array has the
>   field 'part_number' which contains the part number to be fed directly
>   into the imap_fetchbody() function.

```
<?php
function create_part_array($structure, $prefix="") {
    //print_r($structure);
    if (sizeof($structure->parts) > 0) {    // There some sub parts
        foreach ($structure->parts as $count => $part) {
            add_part_to_array($part, $prefix.($count+1), $part_array);
        }
    }else{    // Email does not have a seperate mime attachment for text
        $part_array[] = array('part_number' => $prefix.'1', 'part_object' => $obj);
    }
   return $part_array;
}
// Sub function for create_part_array(). Only called by create_part_array() and itself. 
function add_part_to_array($obj, $partno, & $part_array) {
    $part_array[] = array('part_number' => $partno, 'part_object' => $obj);
    if ($obj->type == 2) { // Check to see if the part is an attached email message, as in the RFC-822 type
        //print_r($obj);
        if (sizeof($obj->parts) > 0) {    // Check to see if the email has parts
            foreach ($obj->parts as $count => $part) {
                // Iterate here again to compensate for the broken way that imap_fetchbody() handles attachments
                if (sizeof($part->parts) > 0) {
                    foreach ($part->parts as $count2 => $part2) {
                        add_part_to_array($part2, $partno.".".($count2+1), $part_array);
                    }
                }else{    // Attached email does not have a seperate mime attachment for text
                    $part_array[] = array('part_number' => $partno.'.'.($count+1), 'part_object' => $obj);
                }
            }
        }else{    // Not sure if this is possible
            $part_array[] = array('part_number' => $prefix.'.1', 'part_object' => $obj);
        }
    }else{    // If there are more sub-parts, expand them out.
        if (sizeof($obj->parts) > 0) {
            foreach ($obj->parts as $count => $p) {
                add_part_to_array($p, $partno.".".($count+1), $part_array);
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```